# Image above or under the

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

this is pretty basic question I'm stuck on. I'm designing my first page with my artistic portfolio and have a problem. I set background to be full screen on any device and wanted to add an image that would appear on the left corner. But I don't know how to code it correctly, it's either image above the background with a white frame or under the background.

It must be something with the divclass line because whether it's above or under the background is dependent putting the image before or after that

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>


body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.bg {

    background-image: url("https://78.media.tumblr.com/9eda2a03998298df51259dc81b0dc0ad/tumblr_p49iilKTmk1x5vw3ao1_1280.jpg");


    height: 100%; 


    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>





    <div class="bg"></div> 
    <img src="<img src="example" alt="example" width="42" height="42">" alt="example" width="42" height="42">





    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RohanPillai you edited the question to include a snippet so at least correct the wrong code, don't leave like that or simply don't change it to a snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can simply consider multiple background and pay attention to order. The **first** image is the **top layer**.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-image:url("https://lorempixel.com/100/100/"), url("https://78.media.tumblr.com/9eda2a03998298df51259dc81b0dc0ad/tumblr_p49iilKTmk1x5vw3ao1_1280.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: top left,center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto,cover;
}
```